# Get Attribute of xml using python etree

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

Here is my `xml`

```
<Departments orgID="1234 " name="This is Demo Name">
  <Department>
   .
   .
  </Department>
  <Department>
   .
   .
  </Department>


</Departments>
```

I want to get attribute of this xml using orgID.

Suppose `orgID=1234` then output should be

```
This is Demo Name
```

What i have tried ,

```
import urllib2
import lxml.etree as ET
url="url goes here"
xmldata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
print root.xpath('//Departments/orgID[text()="1234"]/preceding-sibling::name/text()')[0]
```

But getting error ,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\JAVA\test-img\test\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print root.xpath('//Departments/orgID[text()="1234"]/preceding-sibling::name/text()')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Whats wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: it seems that your xpath matches nothing, because only a empty list can get an index error when you ask for the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `<Departments>` the root of the XML document? If so, then would this be appropriate?

```
import urllib2
import lxml.etree as ET
url="url goes here"
xmldata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)

if root.get('orgID') == "1234":
  print root.get('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

ET doesn't have full xpath support, you should either use lxml or write out the full logic using find, search .attrib, and looping :(

something like

```
root.find("/Departments/orgID").attrib['text']
ect
```

it has been more than a year since I used ET so I cannot help you much more :)